# Entrada de varios inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Não sei como resolver esse problema, o problema pede que eu entre vários inputs de uma vez.
exemplo:

```
10 12
10 14
100 200
```

E após isso dê a diferença entre eles linha a linha,
Eu estava tentando assim:

```
while True:
    try:
        a,b=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
        print(abs(b - a))
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Mano, não ficou muito claro o seu problema

Comment: Ué, seu código funciona: https://ideone.com/bWofJG

Answer (score 0):

Como não posso comentar, vou tentar responder, mas não sei exatamente o que você está querendo resolver. Para dar `break`, o seu código precisa estar dentro de um loop, com isso seu código já funciona normalmente.

```
while True:
  try:
    a,b=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(abs(b - a))
  except EOFError:
    break
```

Agora se as respostas deveriam ser mostradas apenas depois de pegar todas as entradas, armazene as respostas em uma lista e quando sair do loop, mostre as respostas encontradas

```
resultados = []
while True:
    try:
        a,b=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
        resultados.append(abs(b - a))
    except EOFError:
        break

for resultado in resultados:
    print(resultado)
```

Comment: Na verdade ele já estava usando `while True`, o problema é que o código na pergunta  não estava formatado corretamente, [veja o histórico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/8574ed47-dda0-4031-abb1-cfffc40e0110/view-source) - eu arrumei a formatação e agora não dá pra saber qual é o problema, já que o código da pergunta funciona...